# Replacing a kitchen exhaust fan

Tags: electrical, kitchens, exhaust-fan, replacement

Here's an exhaust fan in the ceiling of a kitchen that's probably around 40-50 years old:

[image: Ceiling exhaust fan]

A non-contact voltage detector shows that the fan does get power when the wall switch is flipped on. However the fan doesn't spin.

I'm wondering if this size/shape/type fan is still on the market, or if a similar one could be retrofitted with ease without having to go up into the attic (there's no floor up there).

I wasn't able to find any model/brand written on it.

Comment: The model sticker is under the dust...

Comment: @SolarMike - You see a sticker? The only thing I found was a UL sticker but I don't even see it in the photo.

Comment: @Bort -- can you get us the *file number* off the UL sticker?

Comment: It's probably just gunked up too bad to spin. Does it spin with at little push? 
I would think a replacement fan could be had without knowing the model/manufacturer, etc.  The hole size is probably enough.

Comment: @GregNickoloff - I was hoping to get something like *"Oh, all those kitchen fans from pre-1980 are mostly 'XYZ' fans, which were usually 8 or 12 inches. Just search for XYZ and buy an 8 inch version."* But Idk how many fan types there are, and if there's more to it (perhaps kitchens need a particular rating of fan?)

Comment: @Bort There's a good chance that someone has that kind of information... I don't. I don't think it's that complicated really. Look around and see what you can find. I'm thinking that they're all about the same. If any stand out as being more powerful, etc. you might consider using them.